# How to trap on_error in bash globally?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling, bash-trap

It seems `on_error` trap in Bash works only in the scope of function it was defined in. For instance running this script

```
#!/bin/bash

on_error() {
    echo 'on_error'
}

f() {
    false
    echo 'function f'
}

g() {
    trap on_error ERR
    echo 'function g'
    false
    f
}

g
```

produces:

```
function g
on_error
function f
```

Is there a way to trap `on_error` globally so that I don't have to trap it in each function separately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the `ERR` trap isn't inherited by shell functions.

Quoting from `help set`:

```
  -E  If set, the ERR trap is inherited by shell functions.

  -o option-name
      Set the variable corresponding to option-name:
          errtrace     same as -E
```

Saying

```
set -o errtrace
```

at the beginning of your script should make it work as you expect.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost It turns out that there is a shell option that needs to be set.